# What differences are between these study bibles of NIV?

Tags: bible, reference-request

I found that there are several NIV study bibles, which are all published by Zondervan:

- NIV Archaeological Study Bible, by Walter C. Kaiser Jr.
- NIV Study Bible, Fully Revised, by Kenneth L. Barker
- NIV Biblical Theology Study Bible, by D. A. Carson
- NIV Halleys Study Bible
- NIV Cultural Backgrounds Study Bible Bringing to Life the Ancient World of Scripture, by Keener, Craig S.Walton, John H
- The NIV Zondervan Study Bible, Built on the Truth of Scripture and Centered on the Gospel Message
- NIV Essentials Study Bible (eISBN: 9780310442417)
- NIV Study Bible (eISBN: 9780310437420)
- NIV Bible Study Commentary, by John H. Sailhamer  David A. Frees

What differences are between them? (That will be helpful for me to choose which one to read).

Do they target readers of different interest groups?

Thanks.

Comment: What a dizzying selection!  My NIV Study Bible edition was published in 2000 so I am unable to comment on the ones you have listed.

Comment: If you want to do your own research, check the original publication dates. For instance Halley's was written a hundred years ago (and I imagine this book simply applies his comments to the corresponding verses in the much newer NIV). ¶ Similarly if you have access, read the introductions to each book to determine *why* they thought it a good idea to write yet another (in particular, what did they think was wrong with the existing commentaries?).

Comment: I think this Q is objective enough and already focused enough, as there must be a marketing motivation, with the associated emphasis and target readers) for each NIV study Bible mentioned.  An answer providing a few sentence for each study Bible should be sufficient to capture both emphasis and target audience.  Why is this Q closed?